# Automatic update of image file whenever i change

Tags: photoshop

I am new to photoshop. I am working in psd file and save that result output to .png format in different location. Am working with lots of file undergoes many changes.

Is there any possibility to update my png file if any changes occured in my psd file.
Guide me to sort out this difficulty.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Down voter your comment may help me improve my question

Comment: The reason you were downvoted is because this is a *programming site*.

Comment: So therefore it is reasonable to expect that the OP wants the programmatic answer to their question.  See below.

Comment: You could maybe create an `action` that saves the current document as PNG, and assign the action to a keyboard shortcut, then all you have to do is press say F5 when you want the file saved.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script to save your document and then hook it up to specific events in Photoshop's 'Scripts Event Manager' dialog.  To write your script you'll need to look at the 'saveAs' method on the activeDocument and the PNGSaveOptions object.  You can find all the info you need in the Javascript Ref Guide document in your Photoshop install directory.

You'll wind up with something like this:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var pngOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
//set a bunch of pngOptions as needed

doc.saveAs(new File("/c/temp/temp.png"), pngOptions)
```